# Algorithm: creating hexagons with pillow

Tags: python, algorithm, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a uniform amount of hexagons across a 32 x 32 image. I've been trying to come up with an algorithm that works but have not been able to come up with anything good. This is what I've come up with so far

```
for i in range(0,20):
    im = Image.new("1",(400,400))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        for j in range(i, 20):
           if i > 3 and j > 3:
           half = i/2
           difference = i-half
           z = half/2
           draw.polygon([(z/3,i),(z,half),(z*3,half),(i,i),(z*3,i+difference),(z,i+difference)], fill="white")
           im.show()
```

the issue with this algorithm is the variable z is at 0 (or very close to) unless you get to fairly big numbers, which i'm unfortunately constrained by in my situation. The hexagons don't need to be regular, they just need to "look" like hexagons.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: WARNING: DO NOT RUN THIS CODE WITH THIS INDENTION. IT WILL OPEN 400 WINDOWS

Comment: PS. Don't ask me how I found that out. That's what I get for not reading over something carefully before running it.

Comment: @Zev that gave me a laugh. If anyone wants to debug, remove the `im.show()` command so you don't get windows popping up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason, anyone ever runs into a similar issue, this is what I came up with. If anyone can come up with a quicker solution don't hesitate to post.

```
   for i in range(0,pixels):
    im_rect = Image.new("1", (pixels,pixels))
    draw_rect = ImageDraw.Draw(im_rect)
    for j in range(i, pixels):
        for x in range(i,pixels - i):
            for y in range(j,pixels -j):
                if i > 3 and j > 3 and i +(3*x) < pixels and y+j < pixels:
                    draw.polygon([(i,j),(i+x,y-j),(i+x+x,y-j),(i+(3*x),j),(i+x+x,y+j),(i+x,y+j)], fill="white")
```